# Find $[(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)]^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From a competition archive (again):

> $x,y,z\in\Bbb R^+$ fulfill the following equations:
> $\sqrt{2x-xy}+\sqrt{2y-xy}=1$
> $\sqrt{2y-yz}+\sqrt{2z-yz}=\sqrt2$
> $\sqrt{2z-zx}+\sqrt{2x-zx}=\sqrt3$
> Such that $[(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)]^2$ can be stated as a fraction $\frac mn$, where $m,n$ are coprime positive integers. Find $m+n$.

The answer given is $0.031$ which is clearly not $m+n$ as the question asks for, so let's assume that's (roughly) the value of $\frac mn$.

My attempt:

> Applying that $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ to the first equation:
> $\sqrt{2x-xy}-\sqrt{2y-xy}=2x-xy-(2y-xy)=2x-2y$
> $\sqrt{2x-xy}=\frac{1+2x-2y}2$
> $\sqrt{2y-xy}=\frac{1-2x+2y}2$

> Then, squaring the first equation:
> $2x-xy+2\sqrt{2x-xy}\sqrt{2y-xy}+2y-xy=1$
> $2x-2xy+2\cdot\frac{1+2x-2y}2\cdot\frac{1-2x+2y}2+2y=1$
> $2x+2y-2xy+\frac{1-4x^2+8xy-4y^2}2=1$
> $4x+4y-4xy+1-4x^2+8xy-4y^2=2$
> $0=4x^2+4y^2-4xy-4x-4y+1$

But I'm not sure how to factorize or simplify that equation. I might be going on the wrong direction...

Comment: If you want to continue with this approach, some steps to try are 1/ Find the similar equations for the other two, 2/ Rewrite it using $X = x- 1, Y = y-1, Z = z-1$. EG We have $4X^2 + 4Y^2 - 4XY - 3 = 0 $.

Comment: @CalvinLin alright, I'll give those a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=2\cos^2A, y=2\cos^2B, z=2\cos^2C$ for acute angles $A, B, C$, then we have for the first equation,
$$2\cos A \sin B+2\cos B \sin A=1 \implies \sin(A+B)=\frac12=\sin\frac\pi6 \\ \implies A+B=\frac\pi6$$
Similarly we get for equations (2) and (3):
$$\sin(B+C)=\frac1{\sqrt2}=\sin \frac\pi4\implies B+C=\frac\pi4$$
$$\sin (C+A)=\frac{\sqrt3}2=\sin\frac\pi3\implies C+A=\frac\pi3$$
It is now easily seen that $(A, B, C)=\left(\frac\pi8, \frac\pi{24}, \frac{5\pi}{24} \right)$.  Further rather than find $x, y, z$ we can directly see that $(1-x)^2=(2\cos^2A-1)^2=\cos^22A$, so we need
$$(\cos2A\cdot\cos2B\cdot \cos2C)^2=\cos^22A\cdot \left( \frac{\cos(2B-2C)+\cos(2B+2C)}2\right)^2 \\ =\frac12\cdot \frac{(\frac12+0)^2}4=\frac1{32}$$

---

P.S. That doesn't seem to have much to do with your "given answer" of $0.031$, as $m+n=33$ in this case.  Perhaps there are typos and what was needed was $m-n=31$.  In any case, please double check the workings, did it in a rush...

Comment: I got the same as you. $1/32 = 0.03125$ is how these are related.  (Not sure why the -1)

Comment: Wow, I never even thought that something like this would be possible! This is amazing, thank you